# Oracle instant client deployment?

Tags: oracle, client, installation

Imagine if I have a application I install via clickonce or setup to the customer machine.And it needs oracle client? How can the oracle instant client be installed by the end user ? Or how the hell should it be installed? Should I go to each pc and install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle connection requires SQLNet, an Oracle home, etc. So although you can do instant deployment of .net stuff, the Oracle infrastructure needs to be installed on each and every machine that will connect to the database.

Comment: You mean to tell me that I have to download this
http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html
and install it on each PC.

Comment: I think it should be possible to install the package you mention on a share folder and then you just need to have that folder in the PATH, this way you don't need to touch every machine.

Comment: Oracle Instant Client does not require an ORACLE_HOME on the machine it is installed on (nor an Oracle database on that machine).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do whatever is in the Instant Client installation instructions, which as I recall amounts to copying the files to a folder, and setting the TNS_ADMIN env veriable. It's pretty trivial.

Comment: On Linux you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. ODBC requires an executable to be run (don't know the privileges required to run it)